# Is there a way around the minimum double-click speed being too fast for me?

Tags: mouse, accessibility

I have a disability that makes it difficult for me to double-click quickly enough to be detected, even after setting double-click speed as slow as possible.

[image: screenshot showing Double-Click speed slider set all the way to the slowest extreme]

Is it possible to set it even slower or program a mouse button or key combination to trigger a double-click?

I am using a MacBook Pro (2019) with OS 12.6.5 Monterey.

**Edit**

Commenter Alan helpfully pointed me to [Accessibility Settings specific to the mouse/trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/unac899/13.0/mac/13.0). While that did not enable me to make the speed slower or to assign a key to double-click, it does support setting a facial expression or using a hardware switch, which I can presumably purchase. I successfully set it to register a double-click when I stick out my tongue, which does properly express how I feel about the limitations on speed but is not suitable for when I am teaching online. I will look into buying a switch but would still welcome other hacks that would work with the existing hardware (keyboard or mouse).

Comment: Did you explore any of the [Accessibility Settings specific to the mouse/trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/unac899/13.0/mac/13.0)

Comment: I had not. Thank you for pointing me there. I will update my question.

Comment: Do you have a 'more than 2 buttons' mouse? Many have a button in the scrollwheel mechanism; as well as just simple scrolling action you can press it. That could be set to double-click using something like USB Overdrive or Steer Mouse. [I've had my middle button set as double-click since the mid 90s] These days I have a multi-button Logitech, which can do it from its own control panel - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI4DP.png

Comment: Thank you so much, @Tetsujin! It looks like you found a solution. It seems that any Logitech mouse with their customization software will work, although I haven't been able to find great documentation. I hadn't known about USB Overdrive or Steer Mouse.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'd recommend going to a large high street/retail park computer store, where they'll have a whole aisle full of mice you can test. Comfort/ergonomics you can really only test hands-on. You will also know at a touch if they have a clickable wheel, &/or any other buttons in easy reach that you could assign to this or additional useful tasks. [I actually have the button just below the wheel set to 'close window' or in Email, delete (you can set these globally or per-app)] The more buttons you have in easy reach, the more you can avoid hard-to-reach key combos etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After comments…

Replacing a standard mouse with any that features an extra button inside the scroll-wheel itself would then allow you to set that as double-click [or, in fact, *any* extra button over the standard 2+wheel].

This is a feature of many 'premium' mice. The mouse itself may come with appropriate controlling software to allow you to set this assignment. If not, there is 3rd party software such as [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) or
[USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com) which can enable this [& much more] functionality.

This is a screenshot of part of my own Logitech Options mouse control panel, showing just such a feature, which I have been using in various forms for 30 years, for similar reasons.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. SteerMouse did what I needed without additional hardware. I then decided to buy a Logitech mouse (the Triathlon), and their software allowed me to remap a button so a single click was a double-click. I still wish OS X would accept slightly slower double clicks, but at least I have workarounds.

Comment: Welcome. The advantage of having a double-click button is you can set your system's double-click recognition back to 'normal' & things will double-click faster then you could do it manually, even if you had 'normal' ability. I can actually generate double-clicks at the slowest speeds, but this is just so much slicker & easier for me to do on a repeating basis. After a while you actually forget you're 'cheating' & it just becomes second nature. I'm lost without my own special mouse button setup.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on the [Disabled Techies Slack](https://invite.disabledtechies.org/join) and was told about [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/), which enables mapping many different actions (keypresses, touchpad touches, trackpad actions, mouse clicks) to different actions, including double-click.